# Moving an an entire row from one position to another

Tags: sql

I have 5 rows from my query results and i want to know if its even possible to move an entire row from one position to another. For example the third row to the first row.

Below is my sql code:

```
DECLARE @ClientID int = 1041
DECLARE @ProfileID int =2520
DECLARE @PageType tinyint = 2
BEGIN
WITH SortedList
    AS (
        SELECT PageID, PageName, PageTitle, PageUrl, ParentID, 
            CAST((PageName) AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS "Path"
            FROM Pagelist p
            WHERE p.ParentId IS NULL and p.PageType=@PageType
        UNION ALL
        SELECT p.PageID, p.PageName, p.PageTitle, p.PageUrl, p.ParentID, 
            CAST((a.path + '/' + p.PageName) AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS "Path"
            FROM Pagelist AS p 
                JOIN SortedList AS a
                ON p.ParentID = a.PageID
            WHERE  p.PageType=@PageType                             
       )    
        SELECT a.PageID,a.PageTitle,a.ParentID,ua.Access,a.Path,a.PageName 
        FROM SortedList as a,ProfilePageAccess ua,UserProfile up 
        WHERE ua.ClientID=@ClientID and ua.PageID=a.PageID 
            and up.ProfileID=ua.ProfileID and up.ProfileID=@ProfileID 
        ORDER BY a.Path
```

END

I want to be able to move the third row to first row.

This is my current results

```
PAGEID  PAGETITLE       PARENTID ACCESS  PATH                     PAGENAME
```

```
001R    Administration   801       2     HRAdmin                   HrAdmin
002R    Performance      802       2     HRAdmin/AdminPer          AdminPer
003R    Overall Ratings  803       2     HRAdmin/AdminPerformance  Perform
004R    Score Ratings    804       2     HRAdmin/AdminPerformance  Perform
005R    Template Setup   805       2     HRAdmin/AdminPerformance  Perform
```

Comment: Do you want to apply a different sort order in the select? Or do you think you change the "ordering" of rows in a table? Also: which DBMS are you using? SQL is just a query language, not the name of a database product.

Comment: The ordering of the rows stays the same and i'm using Object-oriented database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ORDER BY you have: `ORDER BY a.Path`

This is ordering by a.Path in ascending (alphabetical) order.

If you want to order by specific values of some other column, you can use an `ORDER BY` with a `CASE` Statement.

ex.

```
...

SELECT a.PageID,a.PageTitle,a.ParentID,ua.Access,a.Path,a.PageName 
        FROM SortedList as a,ProfilePageAccess ua,UserProfile up 
        WHERE ua.ClientID=@ClientID and ua.PageID=a.PageID 
            and up.ProfileID=ua.ProfileID and up.ProfileID=@ProfileID 
        ORDER BY CASE a.PageTitle
                  WHEN 'Overall Ratings' THEN 1
                  WHEN 'Score Ratings' THEN 2
                  ELSE 3
                 END
```

Comment: is it possible to move fourth row to second and the second row to the fourth?

Comment: Add additional lines to the ORDER BY... `WHEN 'Overall Ratings' THEN 1, WHEN 'Performance' THEN 2, WHEN 'Template Setup' THEN 3, WHEN 'Score Ratings' THEN 4, ELSE 5 END`... (or whatever order you want).

Answer (score 0):

One way is to change your ORDER BY to something more complex. For example, in Postgres you could change your query from

`SELECT a.PageID,a.PageTitle,a.ParentID,ua.Access,a.Path,a.PageName`

to

`SELECT a.PageID,a.PageTitle,a.ParentID,ua.Access,a.Path,a.PageName, a.PageID == '003R' as priority_column`

and change

`ORDER BY a.Path`

to

`ORDER BY priority_column DESC, a.Path`

Then it will sort results such that all rows where priority_column is `true` are above all rows where priority_column is `false`.

EDIT: Zorkolot's answer is cleaner than this; probably go with that one.

Comment: Thanks for the help man i really appreciate it but like you said  Zorkolot's answer is exactly what i was looking